# Python Anaconda - no module named numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda on Arch Linux from the Arch repositories. By default, it was set to Python3, whereas I would like to use Python2.7. I followed the Anaconda documentation to create a new Python2 environment. Upon running my Python script which uses Numpy, I got the error `No module named NumPy`. I found this rather strange, as one of the major points of using Anaconda is easy installation of the NumPy/SciPy stack...

Nevertheless, I ran `conda install numpy` and it installed. Now, I still cannot import numpy, but when I run `conda install numpy` it says it is already installed. What gives?

Output of `which conda`: `/opt/anaconda/envs/python2/bin/conda`

Output of `which python`: `/opt/anaconda/envs/python2/bin/python`

Comment: Did you activate the right anaconda environment (source activate <name of python 2.7 environment>)?  You might have installed numpy into the python 3 environment you started with.

Comment: `No module named NumPy`  Is that *literally* what the error says, including the case of the characters?  If so, you should be using `import numpy`, not `import NumPy`.  (If not, you can save the time spent responding to foolish comments such as this one by quoting the full error message *exactly*.)

Comment: @JKelly Yup, python2 is activated with `source activate python2`.

@WarrenWeckesser Nope, the error is `numpy`. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The `anaconda` package in the AUR is broken. If anyone encounters this, simply install `anaconda` from their website. The AUR attempts to do a system-wide install, which gets rather screwy with the path.